# Issues with updating data in sqlite DB from scrapy crawl

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, scrapy

Need some help with trying to update my db based on data scraped from scrapy. What I want to do is for every url scraped run a db select to see if there is a record with that url in the DB (url is the primary key)
Then based on whether or not that rows exists, I run an update but if it doesnt I will call an insert function. Just testing out the DB select, but it seems to keep returning the first row.
When I look at the print from rows it just prints the first row in the DB. It should also print the 2nd row, which contains hamilton beach in the url.

Output -

```
(price_monitor) C:\Users\\Documents\python_venv\price_monitor\price_monitor>scrapy crawl price_monitor
2019-06-23 15:19:20 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.6.0 started (bot: price_monitor)
2019-06-23 15:19:20 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.3.3.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.20.0, Twisted 19.2.0, Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)], pyOpenSSL 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019), cryptography 2.6.1, Platform Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0
2019-06-23 15:19:20 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'price_monitor', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'price_monitor.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['price_monitor.spiders'], 'USER_AGENT': 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36'}
2019-06-23 15:19:20 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 5fcea59cefb35de8
2019-06-23 15:19:20 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2019-06-23 15:19:20 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2019-06-23 15:19:20 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2019-06-23 15:19:20 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['price_monitor.pipelines.PriceMonitorPipeline']
2019-06-23 15:19:20 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-06-23 15:19:20 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-06-23 15:19:20 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-06-23 15:19:21 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2019-06-23 15:19:21 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.amazon.com/BLACK-DECKER-CM4202S-Programmable-Coffeemaker/dp/B07GWKT87L> from <GET https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07GWKT87L/?coliid=I36XKNB8MLE3&colid=KRASGH7290D0&psc=0&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it#customerReview>
2019-06-23 15:19:21 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.amazon.com/Hamilton-Beach-46310-Programmable-Coffee/dp/B07684BPLB> from <GET https://www.amazon.com/Hamilton-Beach-46310-Programmable-Coffee/dp/B07684BPLB/ref=sr_1_10?keywords=coffee+maker&qid=1559098604&s=home-garden&sr=1-10>
2019-06-23 15:19:22 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/BLACK-DECKER-CM4202S-Programmable-Coffeemaker/dp/B07GWKT87L> (referer: None)
print scrapeitem
{'email': 'cobi@noemail.com',
 'name': 'Cobi Maguire',
 'price': '$49.99',
 'title': 'BLACK+DECKER CM4202S Select-A-Size Easy Dial Programmable '
          'Coffeemaker, Extra Large 80 ounce Capacity, Stainless Steel',
 'url': 'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07GWKT87L/?coliid=I36XKNB8MLE3&colid=KRASGH7290D0&psc=0&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it#customerReview'}
print item from process_item
{'email': 'cobi@noemail.com',
 'name': 'Cobi Maguire',
 'price': '$49.99',
 'title': 'BLACK+DECKER CM4202S Select-A-Size Easy Dial Programmable '
          'Coffeemaker, Extra Large 80 ounce Capacity, Stainless Steel',
 'url': 'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07GWKT87L/?coliid=I36XKNB8MLE3&colid=KRASGH7290D0&psc=0&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it#customerReview'}
Inside get data
printing item
<class 'list'>
['BLACK+DECKER CM4202S Select-A-Size Easy Dial Programmable Coffeemaker, Extra Large 80 ounce Capacity, Stainless Steel', '$49.99', 'Cobi Maguire', 'cobi@noemail.com', 'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07GWKT87L/?coliid=I36XKNB8MLE3&colid=KRASGH7290D0&psc=0&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it#customerReview']
print url
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07GWKT87L/?coliid=I36XKNB8MLE3&colid=KRASGH7290D0&psc=0&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it#customerReview
Printing rows
('https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07GWKT87L/?coliid=I36XKNB8MLE3&colid=KRASGH7290D0&psc=0&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it#customerReview', '$49.99')
process item run
2019-06-23 15:19:22 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.amazon.com/BLACK-DECKER-CM4202S-Programmable-Coffeemaker/dp/B07GWKT87L>
{'email': 'cobi@noemail.com',
 'name': 'Cobi Maguire',
 'price': '$49.99',
 'title': 'BLACK+DECKER CM4202S Select-A-Size Easy Dial Programmable '
          'Coffeemaker, Extra Large 80 ounce Capacity, Stainless Steel',
 'url': 'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07GWKT87L/?coliid=I36XKNB8MLE3&colid=KRASGH7290D0&psc=0&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it#customerReview'}
2019-06-23 15:19:22 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/Hamilton-Beach-46310-Programmable-Coffee/dp/B07684BPLB> (referer: None)
print scrapeitem
{'email': 'ryan@noemail.com',
 'name': 'Ryan Murphy',
 'price': '$34.99',
 'title': 'Hamilton Beach 46310 Programmable Coffee Maker, 12 Cups, Black',
 'url': 'https://www.amazon.com/Hamilton-Beach-46310-Programmable-Coffee/dp/B07684BPLB/ref=sr_1_10?keywords=coffee+maker&qid=1559098604&s=home-garden&sr=1-10'}
print item from process_item
{'email': 'ryan@noemail.com',
 'name': 'Ryan Murphy',
 'price': '$34.99',
 'title': 'Hamilton Beach 46310 Programmable Coffee Maker, 12 Cups, Black',
 'url': 'https://www.amazon.com/Hamilton-Beach-46310-Programmable-Coffee/dp/B07684BPLB/ref=sr_1_10?keywords=coffee+maker&qid=1559098604&s=home-garden&sr=1-10'}
Inside get data
printing item
<class 'list'>
['Hamilton Beach 46310 Programmable Coffee Maker, 12 Cups, Black', '$34.99', 'Ryan Murphy', 'ryan@noemail.com', 'https://www.amazon.com/Hamilton-Beach-46310-Programmable-Coffee/dp/B07684BPLB/ref=sr_1_10?keywords=coffee+maker&qid=1559098604&s=home-garden&sr=1-10']
print url
https://www.amazon.com/Hamilton-Beach-46310-Programmable-Coffee/dp/B07684BPLB/ref=sr_1_10?keywords=coffee+maker&qid=1559098604&s=home-garden&sr=1-10
Printing rows
('https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07GWKT87L/?coliid=I36XKNB8MLE3&colid=KRASGH7290D0&psc=0&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it#customerReview', '$49.99')
process item run
2019-06-23 15:19:22 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.amazon.com/Hamilton-Beach-46310-Programmable-Coffee/dp/B07684BPLB>
{'email': 'ryan@noemail.com',
 'name': 'Ryan Murphy',
 'price': '$34.99',
 'title': 'Hamilton Beach 46310 Programmable Coffee Maker, 12 Cups, Black',
 'url': 'https://www.amazon.com/Hamilton-Beach-46310-Programmable-Coffee/dp/B07684BPLB/ref=sr_1_10?keywords=coffee+maker&qid=1559098604&s=home-garden&sr=1-10'}
2019-06-23 15:19:22 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-06-23 15:19:22 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1888,
 'downloader/request_count': 5,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 5,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 261364,
 'downloader/response_count': 5,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 23, 19, 19, 22, 755529),
 'item_scraped_count': 2,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 7,
 'log_count/INFO': 9,
 'response_received_count': 3,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 4,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 4,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 4,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 4,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 23, 19, 19, 20, 885727)}
2019-06-23 15:19:22 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

pipelines.py

```
import sqlite3

class PriceMonitorPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.create_connection()
        self.create_table()

    def create_connection(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("price_monitor.db")
        self.curr = self.conn.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        print("print item from process_item")
        print(item)
        self.get_data(item)
        print("process item run")
        return item

    def get_data(self, item):
        """ Check if the row already exists for this url """
        print("Inside get data")
        item = list(item.values())
        print("printing item")
        print(type(item))
        print(item)

        url = item[-1]
        print("print url")
        print(url)
        self.curr.execute("""select url, new_price from price_monitor WHERE url=url""",
                              {'url': url})

        rows = self.curr.fetchone()

        print("Printing rows")
        print(rows)
```

Items.py
    import scrapy

```
class AmazonItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
    name = scrapy.Field()
    email = scrapy.Field()
```

Myspider.py

```
import scrapy
import json
import sys

from ..items import AmazonItem

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'price_monitor'


    def start_requests(self):
        with open('C:\\Users\\Documents\\python_venv\\price_monitor\\price_monitor\\products.json') as f:
            data = json.load(f)

            itemdatalist = data['itemdata']

            for item in itemdatalist:
                yield scrapy.Request(url=item['url'], callback=self.parse, meta={'item': item}) 


    def parse(self, response):
#        for url in MySpider.start_urls:

        item = response.meta["item"]
        scrapeitem = AmazonItem()

        title = response.css('span#productTitle::text').extract_first()
        title = title.strip()
        price = response.css('span#priceblock_ourprice::text').extract_first()

        scrapeitem['title'] = title
        scrapeitem['price'] = price

        scrapeitem['name'] = item["name"] # from response.meta
        scrapeitem['email'] = item["email"] # from response.meta            
        scrapeitem['url'] = item['url']

        print("print scrapeitem")
        print(scrapeitem)
        yield scrapeitem
```

Comment: "based on whether or not that rows exists, I run an update but if it doesnt I will call an insert function": Why not simplify the whole thing with `REPLACE`?

Comment: Hadnt thought about that, but what I am currently doing should be workable. Why it doesnt work is what I am interested in

Comment: pls use a minimal example when asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Your question contains a lot of code which is most probably nothing to do with your problem and you leave all the work of finding out what the crucial parts are to the community

Comment: Completely understand. But because of the way that scrapy is setup I thought it best that I had to include all the files. The most relevant here is just the pipelines file really, and the output

Answer (score 1):

don't you mean something like

```
self.curr.execute("""select url, new_price from price_monitor WHERE url=?""", url)
```

instead of

```
self.curr.execute("""select url, new_price from price_monitor WHERE url=url""", {'url': url})
```

to me it looks like your version is trying to select the url "url" literally.

Comment: Figured it out, this is the way it had to be -         self.curr.execute("""select url, new_price from price_monitor WHERE url=:url""",
                          {'url': url})